# R, find, dates, consecutive

Tags: r, date, threshold

My job is to find consecutive values in a dataframe beneath a certain threshold.
First I have a extracted a subset from a dataframe with values lower than the threshold. Now my data looks like this:

```
Value       dates
5105.47     1970-03-25
5398.53     1970-04-08
5520.65     1970-04-09
5052.68     1970-04-10
5406.77     1970-04-11
5501.05     1970-04-12
```

The result is basically an irregular time series. Now I would like to identify the consecutive dates. Any guesses on how to do it?

Comment: What would be the desired result in your case? Have you tried `diff`?

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
df1$consecutive <- c(NA,diff(as.Date(df1$dates))==1)
# > df1
#     Value      dates consecutive
# 1 5105.47 1970-03-25          NA
# 2 5398.53 1970-04-08       FALSE
# 3 5520.65 1970-04-09        TRUE
# 4 5052.68 1970-04-10        TRUE
# 5 5406.77 1970-04-11        TRUE
# 6 5501.05 1970-04-12        TRUE
```

By converting the character strings into `Date` format it becomes possible to perform simple operations like taking the difference between two dates. The function `diff()` takes a vector as input and computes the difference between each entry `v[i]` of the vector and its previous entry `v[i-1]`. The difference vector has obviously one entry less than the original vector. Since it is impossible to determine whether the first date in the data.frame is a consecutive one or not, its identifier can reasonably be set to `NA`.

In the case of dates, if the difference is equal to `1` the days are consecutive and the comparison `diff(as.Date(df1$dates))==1)` evaluates to `TRUE`.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Value = c(5105.47, 5398.53, 5520.65, 5052.68, 
            5406.77, 5501.05), dates = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1970-03-25", 
            "1970-04-08", "1970-04-09", "1970-04-10", "1970-04-11", "1970-04-12"),
            class = "factor")), .Names = c("Value", "dates"), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Nice, though I would overwrite df1$dates with its date-formatted version instead of only doing it on the fly.

Comment: Thank you @Frank. I agree, and I would probably do the same. But I noticed a general preference on SO for one-liner type answers ;-)